# PhoneGap Build Malformed Config.xml Error -- Use an XML Validator

Tags: config, phonegap-build

**BIG TIP: USE An XML VALIDATION tool.**

I'd been knocking my head against a wall because of the message from PhoneGap Build ***malformed config.xml error***. I found the clue in a StackOverFlow answer to the question " [When updating code in Phonegap, Malformed config.xml error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199659/when-updating-code-in-phonegap-malformed-config-xml-error)  "

**REMEMBER TO USE AN XML VALIDATION TOOL.** I used http://www.xmlvalidation.com. My first time using it, I kept clicking the check box to "Validate against external XML schema." Don't check this box if you don't have a schema or DTD file. (I'm almost sounding like I know what I am talking about -- still very much a newbie.) The Validator will point you directly to the offending error and line.

My ISSUE:  ***The string "--" is not permitted within comments.***

It can be that minor.

I simply put a space between the string; e.g., **"- -"**.

Hope this tip helps someone else -- even if that is the future me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIG TIP: USE An XML VALIDATION tool.**

I'd been knocking my head against a wall because of the message from PhoneGap Build ***malformed config.xml error***. I found the clue in a StackOverFlow answer to the question " [When updating code in Phonegap, Malformed config.xml error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199659/when-updating-code-in-phonegap-malformed-config-xml-error)  "

**REMEMBER TO USE AN XML VALIDATION TOOL.** I used http://www.xmlvalidation.com. My first time using it, I kept clicking the check box to "Validate against external XML schema." Don't check this box if you don't have a schema or DTD file. (I'm almost sounding like I know what I am talking about -- still very much a newbie.) The Validator will point you directly to the offending error and line.

My ISSUE:  ***The string "--" is not permitted within comments.***

It can be that minor.

I simply put a space between the string; e.g., **"- -"**.

Hope this tip helps someone else -- even if that is the future me.